# Wrong remapping of keypoints of the object after image rotation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, rotation

I have image with with many cars, every car has coordinates of polygon and keypoints. I use this code to crop object by polygon and get new keypoints.

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(points_poly_int)
cropped_img = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

head_coords_after_crop = np.asarray([head_coords_old[0] - x, head_coords_old[1] -y])
center_coords_after_crop = np.asarray([center_coords_old[0] - x, center_coords_old[1] -y])
```

Here example of cropped image and keypoints:

[image]

What I need is rotate the whole image by any angle and remap coordinates of polygons and keypoints for every object

Here method which return rotated image and matrix of transformation:

```
def rotate_image(mat, angle):
    """
    Rotates an image (angle in degrees) and expands image to avoid cropping
    """

    height, width = mat.shape[:2] # image shape has 3 dimensions
    image_center = (width/2, height/2) # getRotationMatrix2D needs coordinates in reverse order (width, height) compared to shape

    rotation_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.)

    # rotation calculates the cos and sin, taking absolutes of those.
    abs_cos = abs(rotation_mat[0,0]) 
    abs_sin = abs(rotation_mat[0,1])

    # find the new width and height bounds
    bound_w = int(height * abs_sin + width * abs_cos)
    bound_h = int(height * abs_cos + width * abs_sin)

    # subtract old image center (bringing image back to origo) and adding the new image center coordinates
    rotation_mat[0, 2] += bound_w/2 - image_center[0]
    rotation_mat[1, 2] += bound_h/2 - image_center[1]

    # rotate image with the new bounds and translated rotation matrix
    rotated_mat = cv2.warpAffine(mat, rotation_mat, (bound_w, bound_h))
    return rotated_mat, rotation_mat
```

What I do next is multiplying old coordinates with matrix of transformation. Here code:

```
img_roated, C = rotate_image(img, 180)

#Remap polygons coordinates
ones = np.ones((points_poly.shape[0], 1))
new_poly = np.hstack((points_poly,ones))
new_poly = (C @ new_poly.T).T
new_poly =  new_poly.astype(np.int32)

#Crop by new polygons
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(new_poly)
cropped_img = img_roated[y:y+h,x:x+w]

#Reamp keypoints coordinates
head_coords_new = np.asarray([756.600, 1687.900, 1])
center_coords_new = np.asarray([762.300, 1708.400, 1])
head_coords_new = (C @ head_coords_new.T).T
center_coords_new = (C @ center_coords_new.T).T

head_coords_new = np.asarray([head_coords_old[0] - x, head_coords_old[1] - y])
center_coords_new = np.asarray([center_coords_old[0] - x, center_coords_old[1] - y])

head_coords_new =  head_coords_new.astype(np.int32)
center_coords_new =  center_coords_new.astype(np.int32)
```

But result is differnt from first picture, Here new picture:

[image]

Somehow keypoints shift, and it happens with every angle. And I don't know how to fix it.

Here the source image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14K_MQHMwtWlw-QCQbaB5ecrREbWwyKhO/view?usp=sharing

And polygons with keypoints:

```
{'keypoints': [{'id': 'head', 'pos': '756.600;1687.900'},
  {'id': 'roof_center', 'pos': '762.300;1708.400'}],
 'polygon': '{(759.700;1717.300);(770.000;1714.200);(762.000;1687.400);(756.600;1687.900);(751.200;1690.700);(759.700;1717.300)}'}
```

If you wish to reproduce the issue.

Thanks in advnced

Here the differnce. Right pic is first image rotated in pic viewer. Left is transformed pic
[image]

Comment: that is an incredibly tiny picture. why? -- if you examine your heaps of pixels _very closely_, like with serious magnification, you'll notice they're oriented exactly half a turn to each other.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, pictures are tiny because of quality of source image. It's only 4K, that not enough to crop small objects with good resolution. About rotations, if you rotate first image by 180 in pic viewer, you'll see the differences. Added comparisons